# Journey planner for finding intercity train connections in China?

Tags: trains, online-resources, china

Are there any search engines/journey planners that can provide **intercity train connections** in China?

Specifically, I'm looking for something like Japan's [Jorudan](https://world.jorudan.co.jp/mln/en/), which will happily suggest both direct and connecting trains. The standard ones that show up on Google, like [Ctrip](https://english.ctrip.com/trains/) or [China.org.cn](http://trains.china.org.cn/), only seem to be able to provide direct, one-train connections. English preferred, but I'll tackle Chinese if I have to.

Comment: Do you have an example of an A->B itinerary where both direct connections and A->C->B connections exist and make sense? I mean you could travel Beijing to Shanghai also via Xian but what are your criteria to include such connections?

Comment: @mts Actual inspiration for this question: we're going from Beijing to Xining, but the direct overnight train is full and connections via Xi'an don't show up in searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found two ways to do this, but both require knowing at least a bit of Chinese.

1. The **clunky but straightforward way** is to use the ctrip.com website in Chinese, select **中转** from the far-left dropdown, and manually input the connecting city.  (This feature is not available on the English version of the site.)  Here's [Beijing to Xining via Xi'an](http://trains.ctrip.com/TrainBooking/HubRoundTrip.aspx?from=beijing&to=xining&day=2018-08-27&hub=xian&hubCn=%CE%F7%B0%B2&number=&fromCn=%B1%B1%BE%A9&toCn=%CE%F7%C4%FE) (only), with Beijing-Xi'an trains on the left and Xi'an-Xining trains on the right:

[image]

2. The **slick but more labor-intensive way** is to install the [Chinese Ctrip app aka 携程旅行](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ctrip.android.view&hl=en_US), and then just do a regular train search, which will automatically show suitable connections through any city.  Here's Beijing to Xining again, which shows those connections through Xi'an:

[image]

Hat tip to [the friendly folk at /r/china for pointing the way](https://www.reddit.com/r/travelchina/comments/8pa26r/train_connection_searchtravel_planner/).

Comment: Ctrip has an English language site on [Trip.com](https://trip.com), but it doesn't seem to have this connecting city feature for train searches.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee That's right, and I've now called this out -- thanks!